# Intellij ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/person

Tags: database, hibernate, intellij-idea, hibernate-mapping

first of all I couldn't find an answer from related questions in this forum. I am new to Hibernate technology and I am trying to run a basic example from this page: http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4/firstHibernateApplication.shtml
 Although, in eclipse it worked fine, I've got a problem with Intellij IDEA. Specifically, I have an error in the hibernate.cfg.xml file which says:

" 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' is not assignable to 'java.sql.Driver' ".

And when I run the program a message appears saying: 
"ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/person Inserting Record Could not open connection"

('person' is my database) I have added the necessary jar files (or at least I think so) and generally I have followed all the steps from the webpage I pasted in the second line of this message. Please look at it and help me if you can. All the files and code I've created can be seen from the website I pasted. I've almost copied-pasted the example. Thank you.

***UPDATED***

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/person
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I' ve placed the connector jar file at the directory IdeaProjects\coreHibernateExample\lib. No, I am not running Tomcat, I guess I am running through Intellij. The import of the Mysql database has been made through Wampservers' phpmyadmin.

Comment: Could you post your config file?  Also, can you tell me (us) if you are running Tomcat (or whatever app server) on its own or through IntelliJ?  Also, where did you place the MySQL Connector/j Jar file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the JDBC library jar available to your project. Just adding jar to your project directory does not accomplish that.

Select jar in your project, right click and add as a library.

[image]