# Exception when adding hibernate library to project in Intellij Idea

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, intellij-idea

This image shows which library (hibernate) I add in my project in NetBeans and it works well.

I wish this to work in IntelliJ Idea, but when I tried to add some hibernate library in IntelliJ it throws an exception

IntelliJ
[image: IntelliJ idea]

Exception message.
[image]

Comment: You didn't post any details about your problem. No error message, no screenshot from IntelliJ. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: @defaultlocale I post image bellow question in link

Comment: Wait where this exception comes from? It doesn't look like an IDE issue. If it happens when you actually run your application, then tell exactly what have you done, otherwise you're making it impossible to help you. Also, you should post exception message and related code as text.

Comment: This is GUI application I develop over JavaFX techology,this exception eject when I run project...
The application communicates with MySQL database on my computer over Hibernate,but eject exception.I have no idea what it is?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151903/intellij-error-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-127-0-0-13306-person I'm not sure if it helps, I just searched for exception message

Comment: Have you added the MySQL driver as an external reference?

Comment: @BadHeuristics yes,solved problem somehow...

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans-specific project structure won't work in other IDEs, so I recommend you use [Maven](https://gradle.org/) or [Gradle](https://maven.apache.org/). If you use these, your project won't be strongly tied to your IDE and your external JARs won't have to be checked into source control.

Otherwise, you can paste your jars into the /lib folder, right-click them, and choose "Add as Library."